# Adding a Voice Recording Feature in React Native App

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to add a feauture in my React Native App to be able to create a voice note and send send it in my Django Backend(POST API).

I am using `import AudioRecorderPlayer from 'react-native-audio-recorder-player';` library.

In my component, I created Buttons using TouchableOpacity. The buttons are "Start Recording", "Stop Recording", and "Play Audio".

When I use any of those buttons to call my methods, I get the following Error:

```
[00:09:51] null is not an object (evaluating 'RNAudioRecorderPlayer.startPlayer')
at node_modules\react-native-audio-recorder-player\index.ts:null in AudioRecorderPlayer#startPlayer
at node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:null in asyncGeneratorStep
at node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:null in _next
at node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:null in Promise$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:null in tryCallTwo
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:null in doResolve
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:null in Promise
at node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:null in <anonymous>
at node_modules\react-native-audio-recorder-player\index.ts:null in AudioRecorderPlayer
```

Below is my code:

```
const startRecording = async () => {
    try {
      const path = await audioRecorderPlayer.startRecorder();
      audioRecorderPlayer.addRecordBackListener((e) => {
      this.setState({
        recordSecs: e.currentPosition,
        recordTime: this.audioRecorderPlayer.mmssss(Math.floor(e.currentPosition)),
      })
    })
      setAudioPath(path);
      console.log(path)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

  const stopRecording = async () => {
    try {
      const path = await audioRecorderPlayer.stopRecorder();
      audioRecorderPlayer.removeRecordBackListener((e) => {
        this.setState({
          recordSecs: 0,
        })
      })
      setAudioPath(path);
      console.log(path)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  const playRecording = async () => {
    try {
      await audioRecorderPlayer.startPlayer(audioPath);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

Outside of my component is the instance of AudioRecordPlayer();

```
const audioRecorderPlayer = new AudioRecorderPlayer();
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope this will help you.

```
const audioRecorderPlayer = useRef(new AudioRecorderPlayer()).current;
```

that is how i solved my error